# ACR122U - when transmitting APDU

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard

I am making a native module for use in react native. i use ACR122U to recognize the nfc tag and send it to the react native view. But the data is broken. Is it an encoding problem?

```
int responseLength = reader.transmit(params.slotNum,
                                sendBuffer, sendBuffer.length, response, response.length);
String charsetName = "UTF-8";
                            reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                                    .emit("CardData", new String(response, 0, responseLength,charsetName));
```